# Book navigation that expands to child page from a non-linked header

Tags: nodes, navigation

I have a site with many books, some of them fairly large. I have it set up so that there is a book navigation block on the right hand side of the page. I want to be able to expand the navigation block to enable child pages to be viewed. However, the parent page of the children does not have content in it. Thus, it seems silly to have to click and empty page, wait for the browser to refresh, just so I can view children pages, so I can click again to get the child pages. It is a very disjointed experience for a user.

I am looking for a solution that can look something like this:

- Top book page
- P1
- P2 (<-- this page has no content, it is a header that describes the kinds of pages below)
- -1 child of p2
- -2 child of p2
- -3 child of P2
- P3
- P4

In this case, clicking P2 would expand its children, but not navigate away from whatever page you are on. Preferably, this would be a solution that I could implement site-wide, rather than perform individually for every single book (there are many books, and they will be updated periodically, so a automated solution is obviously ideal).

I am currently having difficulty understand why no-one else (to my knowledge) has had this difficulty, or why there are no contributed modules to help with this. Perhaps I am missing something obvious.

I am using Drupal 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: This module will solve your problem [Special menu items](https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have seen this module, but I do not think it has all the functionality I want. First, I am unclear how it can be used within a book navigation. Second, it creats static dividers, and does not alow for expanding and collapsing (to my knowledge). Am I missing something?

Comment: Just add a new menu item for books, for example: link title `books` link path `<nolink>` select `show as expanded`

Comment: I must still be missing something. I am unsure how a menu item can be displayed within the book navigation. To my knowledge, a book navigation block is not treated as a menu. I am attempting to have the non-clickable item within the book navigation block. Further, I am hoping that the user can expand and collapse the item (as some books are very large and an entire toc displaying at once is not ideal). I am unable to get this module to do either of these things.

Comment: I believe I could help, but not sure where exactly the problem is. Could you edit your question and provide some screenshots or links, something which might help to understand the problem?

Comment: I shared some images off of dropbox. I hope they are helpful in demonstrating what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Your menu works fine, it just require some theming. Alternatively have a look at [Superfish menu](https://drupal.org/project/superfish) or [TB Megamenu](https://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) and this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnuhbFwsJ3M)

Comment: @Ein sköpuðr galdra I'm having the same issue. Have you solve this issue yet? Are you using more than one Book content type?